# How to add custom domain to azure app service with existing akamai edge hostname

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

We are trying to add a custom domain that integrates an Akamai edge hostname which we have already setup with our Azure App Service.  The goal here is this mappping :

site.com -> site.com.edgekey.net -> site.azurewebsites.net

However in the App Service custom domain blade you can only go from :

site.com -> site.azurewebsites.net.

There is no way I can see that you can add the Akamai edge hostname.  I've looked at the Azure CDN option but that only allows you to purchase CDN service from Azure, then integrate that into your App Service.

Is there a way to integrate an Akamai edge hostname into an Azure App Service custom domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, we can add a root domain `contoso.com` or a subdomain `www.contoso.com` or a wildcard domain `*.contoso.comin` in the **custom domain** of web app service. You could follow this tutorial: [Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

However, in this case, if you have custom domain `site.com` to the custom domain of web app service, you can add its subdomain `sub1.site.com` to the hostname. If you want to map `site.com.edgekey.net -> site.azurewebsites.net` you at least need a domain `com.edgekey.net`, then you can use a CNAME record name `site` in such domain `com.edgekey.net` to your web app service. I think it's impossible as the domain `com.edgekey.net` is not compatible.

If you want to use Azure CDN, Azure CDN support to add your custom domain to Azure CDN endpoint. You could view the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain). Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Hi Nancy, let me rephrase the question.  I think I presented it incorrectly.  What I need to do is this :  site.contosso.com -> site.contosso.com.edgekeys.net -> my-site.azurewebsites.net.  We are using a subdomain of our domain as a custom domain for our app service.  We would like to use the edge hostname of Akamai to speed up loading our site.  That is why we want to integrate Akamai edge hostname.

Comment: I think I could understand your question. As my reply, it's impossible to integrate Akamai edge hostname with Azure web app service. Azure web app could integrate with Azure CDN in order to speed up your web sites.